# How to set button color of a storyboard to a common color without connecting the outlet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have a storyboard with few viewcontrollers i need to set a common color for buttons but some of the buttons outlets are not connected is there any way to set common color by editing storyboard xml or something

Comment: https://blog.zeplin.io/asset-catalog-colors-on-xcode-9-c4fdccc0381a

Comment: do you want to set all buttons color of your app or just specific storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Create new class for on which you want to add custom properties

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class ButtonColorBlockView: UIButton {

@IBInspectable var blockColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = blockColor
    }
   }
}
```

In the storyboard added background colour as default refers image
[image]

**Detail Reference** https://medium.com/bpxl-craft/working-with-ibdesignable-807739869b36